# My ASP.NET website displays a paper icon at taskbar for Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, google-chrome

I just get a ASP.NET web site. It use JavaScript, JQuery, and jqGrid. I use Chrome to open the website. The first page has a button. Press that and a new page will pop up. This pop up page does not show regular Chrome icon. Instead it shows the following 'paper' icon. Is there any way to change this 'paper' icon back to the Chrome icon?

I try the web site using Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer 11 (both are not supported browser by this web site). Both shows regular icon when the pop up page comes up.

Here is a bit of detail:
First page is popup.aspx with a login button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
....
// if staff id is empty,
window.open('AfterLogin.aspx?id= ...
```

The button will pop up page called AfterLogin.aspx. It basically is empty, but it uses master page. In the master page, it do some checking and redirect to the login.aspx page.

[image]

Comment: Isn't that the default blank favicon? I think it's just the browser's behaviour to use it for opened windows. You can refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40177033/how-to-make-the-favicon-appear-in-a-new-window to change it only for the opened window so you can use the chrome icon with a browser check if you don't want your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel=icon" href="images/myIcon.ico"></link>
```

Put this link in your head tag and provide your image url to get that icon which you want to show instead of paper icon

Comment: That works! After a bit of research, your answer is saying to add a favicon. It looks to me favicon is the icon beside the address bar in a browser (from https://tutorialehtml.com/en/what-is-favicon-ico-usage/). Don't know why it _can_ change the icon in the Windows taskbar!